# Why is this equation not a sturm-liouville equation??

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

The equation is $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = k\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2} - V_o\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$$

By seperation of variables we obtain for the x problem : $k\alpha'' -V_o\alpha' + \lambda\alpha =0$
The SL equation is in form $p\alpha'' +p'\alpha' +q\alpha +\lambda\alpha =0$ 
Why can't $p=k, p'=-V_o$?? q can be equal to zero and it would work??

Comment: It isn't, the question is as follow, "Show that the spatial ordinary differential equation obtained by seperation of variables is not in Sturm-Liouville form".

Comment: How can $p=k$ and $p' \ne 0$?  That is the reason that it is not SL.